# Remove a newline before a regex-matched line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have 5 lines

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Using regex I've matched the line3. Now is there I way I can move the line3 just after line2(in other words, do away with the \n at the end of line2)?

I plan on using `line3.sub(/myregex/, "some way to pull up line3 right after line2")` method.

or I can do `line2.sub(/regex_to_select_the_/n_at_the_end/, "")`. Will this work?

Is there a better/different way to do it?

Comment: Regular expressions have a single purpose; find patterns of text. Once you find it, you're almost always better off using another tool to manipulate that data.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the regex you used to match `line3` into a lookahead expression, search for a `\n` before that and replace it with nothing:

```
result = subject.gsub(/\n(?=regex)/, '')
```

(where `regex` is your regex).